# How can I programmatically add webform elements to an existing webform?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform that is very simple, it's a questionnaire. It is attached to a content type called "event". e.g.

```
discussion_1:
  '#type': likert
  '#title': 'Discussion 1'
  '#questions':
    'Question 1': 'Question 1'
    'Question 2': 'Question 2'
    'Question 3': 'Question 3'
  '#answers': likert_five_scale
```

Is it possible to alter this webform when the webform is rendered by populating the questions from another source such as a view?

i.e. there will be a variable number of discussions with variable numbers of questions.

I am trying to dynamically build a webform based on data that is coming from the node to which the webform is attached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [hook_webform_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load/8.2.x) and alter a webform's elements via `\Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform::setElements`. If you trying the alter webform elements based on the node (aka source entity) you might need to use [hook_webform_submission_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_load/8.2.x) and then alter the webform's element via `\Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformSubmission::getWebform`

Comment: Thanks Jacob, as usual you live up to your name - You Rock! How do you get so much time to help people out?

Answer (score 5):

So I spent a full day investigating on something similar. Kudos to @jrockowitz for providing the right direction. Below is something I wrote to work.

```
$webforms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('webform')
  ->loadByProperties([]);

$new_field = [
   'new_field'=>[ '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => 'Question one',]];

foreach ($webforms as $webform) {
     // Applying to all forms.
      if (!in_array('new_field', $webform->getElementsDecoded())) {
        // $webform->getElementsDecoded() will get all the previous elements of the webform.
        $new_element_arrangment = array_merge($webform->getElementsDecoded(), $new_field);
        $webform->setElements($new_element_arrangment)->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask where are you using this code? Because if you follow the advice from Jacob, you don't need to load webforms to loop over them.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module and use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.7.x) to add new fields and set default values.

```
function YOURMODULENAME_form_alter($form_id, &$form) {
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_FORM_ID') { 
        $form['yourmodule'] = array(
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#options' => t('Test'),
        '#title' => t('Title),
        '#description' => t('Description.'),
        '#weight' => 100,
    );
  }
}
```